# Migrating ASP.NET MVC Routes to ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I am learning ASP.NET vNext. To do that, I decided to port my existing app over to vNext. The thing I'm not sure about is, how to port over my routes.

In my origin ASP.NET MVC app, I have the following:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Index",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Root", action = "Index" }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Items",
    url: "items/{resource}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Root", action = "Items", resource = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BitcoinIntegration",
    url: "items/available/today/{location}",
    defaults: new { controller="Root", action="Availability", location=UrlParameter.Optional }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BlogPost1",
    url: "about/blog/the-title",
    defaults: new { controller = "Root", action = "BlogPost1" }
  );
}
```

Now in this ASP.NET vNext world, I'm not sure how to setup routes. I have the following:

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Routing;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyProject.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseErrorPage();

            app.UseServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddMvc();
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}");
            });

            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseWelcomePage();
        }
    }
}
```

Still, I'm not sure of two things:

1. How to add the routes I defined in RouteConfig.cs previously.
2. How to use `views/home/Index.cshtml` as my default path in place of `app.UseWelcomePage()`.

Comment: What's wrong with `app.UseMvc(routes => RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes))`? This is not a vNext distinction, it is just regular MVC except you are using OWIN to bootstrap your app rather than explicitly registering your routes in Global.asax. Routing works the same, you are just calling `RegisterRoutes` from a different place. As for your other Home/Index issue, just remove the call to `UseWelcomePage` - your routing will do what it would have done otherwise.

Comment: @AntP - Is there a more "recommended" approach in vNext? I'm trying to be as consistent as possible with vNext so that I learn it the correct way.  Thank you.

Comment: You still need to include your routes in the delegate you're passing to `UseMvc` - whether or not you call `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes)` in there or just declare an anonymous delegate and add all the routing code there (like in your current example) really makes very little difference. I'd probably keep it in `RouteConfig` though just to avoid bloating the `Configure` method. vNext convention would just dictate that you use OWIN to bootstrap your application (rather than use the `Global.asax` approach), which you are already doing.

Answer (score 4):

**Registering routes:**
There are few changes but the overall approach remains same. Here's your refactored `RouteConfig`:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Routing;

public class RouteConfig 
{
  // instead of RouteCollection, use IRouteBuilder
  public static void RegisterRoutes(IRouteBuilder routes)
  {
    // routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); -> gone
    // routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; -> gone

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Index", 
      template: "", 
      defaults: new { controller = "Root", action = "Index" }
    );

    // instead of UrlParameter.Optional, you use the ? in the template to indicate an optional parameter
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Items", 
      template: "items/{resource?}", 
      defaults: new { controller = "Root", action = "Items" }
    );

    ... // ignored for brevity (since their registration is along the same lines as the above two).
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  // ... other startup code
  
  app.UseMvc(RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes);  
  
  // ... other startup code
}
```

**Note**: You can very well inline the route registration here, but I prefer having it in separate file to de-clutter `Startup.cs`

To point `UseWelcomePage` to one of your own, look at the different overloads [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.welcomepageextensions.usewelcomepage(v=vs.113).aspx).

**Disclaimer:** Since vNext is still in beta is undergoing churn every hour, the code I show here could quickly become outdated, even in the next minute or the next hour!

Comment: Do I need to register RouteConfig as a transient service and inject it to Configure method ?

Comment: I think that would be an overkill.

Comment: How about setting the optional value with a fallback in the `defaults` object? For instance: `defaults: new { controller = "Root", action = "Items", resource = "" }`